When I load localhost:3000 with the following code in node.js, nothing recieved by the webpage. Why is this?
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
console.log(req.url, req.method, req.headers);
//process.exit();
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'test/html');
res.write('<html>');
res.write('<head><title>My first page</title></head>');
res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Server</h1></body>');
res.write('</html>');
res.end();

});

server.listen(3000);

Im expecting the page to say Hello form my Node.js but instead nothing is recieved

Because content type is not valid,
'Content-Type', 'test/html'

should be
'Content-Type', 'text/html'

Valid Content-Types can be found here https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
The correct code will be
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url, req.method, req.headers);
    //process.exit();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>My first page</title></head>');
    res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Server</h1></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();

});

server.listen(3000);

I tested this in node 20 but should work on any version you are using
